# How to implement a destructor

Tags: c++, c++17

I am having trouble to understand vector and heap. So far, I want to create a vector of int. The element of this vector should be stored in the heap. I have implemented a class, but I don't think that I have implement the destructor correctly. There is also a problem with the move constructor. If I want to move vector a to vector b, a stays with the same values.

```
Class A {
private : 
vector<int> myV ;
int val; 
size_t Size; 
public: 
    A(){
    myV.resize(0);      
this->value = 0 ;
   }

A(size_t size){
    MyVector.resize(0);
    Size = size ;
    this->value = 0 ;
}

A(size_t size, int value){
    A.resize(0);
    Size = size;
    Val = value;
    MyVector.push_back(Val);
}
~A()
{
     myV.clear();
     delete &myV;
}
    A(A&&other)
{
    *this = std::move(other);
    this->myV = other.myV ;
}
```

I tried to check the code, But

```
int main()
{
    Vector myVect(2,5);
    Vector m (std::move(myVect));
    std::cout<<m[0]<<std::endl;
}
```

values of myVect is not moved, though it stayed as they are.

From what I understood that vector should allocate the element on the heap, how can I release it where there isn't memory leak.

Comment: Yes, you did not implement the destructor correctly. What exactly is being `new`ed, that your destructor is attempted to `delete`? Why do you believe you need to release anything that the vector allocate on its own? Why do you think that's your job to do, instead of vector's? After all, the vector allocated it, why do you think  you need to delete it, instead of the vector? Isn't that what vector is for, in the first place?

Comment: `delete &myV;` can never ever be correct. Don't ever write code like that

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I am still confused about this issue. If vector<int> allocates a memory on the heap, then where I put 'new' when adding an int on the code.

Comment: What exactly do you expect the line `*this = std::move(other);` to do? You haven't implemented your own `operator=(A&&)`. Are you sure the compiler-generated one will work correctly? If so, why do you expect `other.myV` to still be meaningful after `other` was moved from?

Comment: You are correct. vector allocates memory on the heap. So, what then? Which part of your C++ textbook led you to believe that it's your job to delete this memory, instead of the vector's? Looks like you're misunderstanding some part of your textbook's explanation of how vector works. Can you briefly quote, exactly, why you believe that there's anything that needs to be `delete`d? Just because some part of the C++ library allocated something on the heap doesn't mean that it's your program's job to delete it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik From what I understand from your comment, in a case to ensure that no memory is leaked in my example. I would clear the vector by the clear function.. So, I don't think I need to use delete.

Comment: Why do you believe you need to explicitly clear the vector? How does your C++ textbook explain what happens when the vector gets destroyed, whether explicitly cleared, or not. What difference does it make? `clear()` does not necessary free any memory.

Comment: @Saleh The beauty of `std::vector` is that it calls `delete` automatically, in its destructor. A good rule of thumb is if you didn't *manually* call `new`, you don't need to *manually* call `delete`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat In that case, how can I be sure that that there is no memory leaked? I am really confused.

Comment: By trusting `std::vector`? Or by using various leak detectors (how exactly you do that depends on your OS and compiler).

Comment: The right thing to do here is to remove the custom move constructor and the destructor, and let the compiler generate them, unless you want to practice writing them ([rule of zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat well, as you stated, I want to practice writing them. I got your point. I will just then, remove elements from my vector.

Comment: For proper practice, I would call `new manually. The apply a leak detector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below a working example.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream> // Debug only

class Vector
{
    private:
        std::vector<int> _myVec;
        int _val;
        size_t _size;

    public:
        // "Regular" Construtors
        Vector() : _val(0), _size(0) {}
        Vector(size_t size) : _size(size), _val(0) {}

        Vector(size_t size, int value) : _val(value), _size(size)
        {
            _myVec.push_back(_val);
        }

        // Move Constructor
        Vector(Vector&& other)
        {
            std::cout << "Move Constructor called\n"; // Debug purpose

            _myVec = std::move(other._myVec);
            _val = std::move(other._val);
            _size = std::move(other._size);
        }

        // Destructor
        ~Vector()
        {
            _myVec.clear(); // useless being given the destructor will destroy the vector of int anyway
        }

        // Getter
        std::vector<int> getMyVec() const { return _myVec; }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world\n";

    Vector _myVecect(2, 5);
    Vector m(std::move(_myVecect));

    std::cout << m.getMyVec()[0] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When you create a move constructor, you have to move every members of the class, like it is done above ^.
For your cout line in your main, this can't work like because your variable 'm' is an instance of your class Vector. You cannot manipulate it through the [] operator unless you define it yourself to work with it like it is an array.

You don't need this kind of destructor doing this being given you do not manage streams or dynamic memory. If you have a stream, the destructor would be a good place to close to ensure no one will try to use the stream after the object deletion.
In the case of dynamic memory, you would not have to use delete here because we now have in modern C++ smart pointers (unique_ptr and smart_ptr that do the job for you).

Comment: **If** you're providing a custom move constructor (which is unnecessary here), you also need custom copy constructor and copy/move assignment; otherwise the compiler refuses to generate them. After you remove the move constructor, the custom destructor is not only useless, but also harmful, since it prevents move operations from being generated, unless you `=default` them.

Comment: Yep I agree with you on the triviality of both destructor and move constructor for this sample of code @HolyBlackCat, maybe Saleh was trying to play around with them, so I just completed the move one to make its main works.

Comment: @Saleh note that you don't need, for the use case you gave, to explictly resize and clean your vector that is a member of your class. The std::vector class will manage this kind of things for you.
Here is a link if you want to use the [] operator like you tried in your main instead of a getter like I did : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators
See the chapter "Array subscript operator"

Comment: @user17732522 thanks for the noexcept point, I forgot that and so edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should read about the rule of 0 (eg [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), it starts with rule of 3/5, make sure to read till the end).

`std::vector` already manages the memory for you. You also should not implement a move constructor when it does nothing more than the compiler generated one can do. Moreover you should use the member initialzer list to initialize members. Though a default constructed `std::vector` is already of size 0, no need to resize it. And you forgot to initialize `Size` in the default constructor, its also not moved in the move constructor. I suppose `Size` should be the size of the vector, but the vector already keeps track of its size, so I removed that member. I further suppose that `val` is some value you want to store in the vector, so there is no need to have it duplicate as member.

Your class can look like this:

```
class A {
    std::vector<int> myV ;
public: 
    A() = default;
    A(size_t size) : myV(size) {}    
    A(size_t size, int value) : myV(size,value) {}
    std::vector<int> get() { return myV; }
};
```